# How to generate a random question from firebase to a quiz app?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create my first android app. I have created quiz, connected with Firebase. It works fine, but I need to show only 10 questions - from the total 30, randomly. Also, I don't want to repeat the question.  How can I generate random question? Here is the code I made. Thanks

```
private void updateQuestion() {
    mQuestionRef = new Firebase("https://ab-quiz.firebaseio.com/"+ mQuestionNumber +"/biq");
    mQuestionRef.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String question = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mQuestion.setText(question);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
            if(mQuestionNumber > 10){

                quitFunction();

            }
            else {
                mQuestionNumber++;
            }
}
```

Comment: what is your question here? please clarify

Comment: My questuion is  how to  generate random question, without repetition?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Add all your questions in a List.
2. Maintain a count of how many questions have you displayed starting with 0.
3. Use the code below to get a random number within your list size.

   ```
   Random rand = new Random();    
   int n = rand.nextInt(list.size);
   ```
4. Get the question from your list using `list.get(n)`.
5. After your question is displayed remove the item from the list using `list.remove(n)`.
6. Increment your count of how many questions have you displayed declared in step 2.
7. Start another process after you have reached your limit of displaying questions.

Hope this helps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible answer -

Firstly, you should create a QuizQuestion.java where you can set a questionId and the questionText, like this -

```
public class QuizQuestion {

    private int questionId;
    private String questionText;

    public ChatMessage(int questionId, String questionText, ) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
        this.messageUser = messageUser;
    }

    public QuizQuestion(){

    }

    public int getQuestionId() {
        return questionId;
    }

    public void setQuestionId(int questionId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }

    public String getQuestionText() {
        return questionText;
    }

    public void setQuestionText(String questionText) {
        this.questionText = questionText;
    }
}
```

Then, call it in MainActivity.java -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView questionView;
    private Button nextButton;

    private int questionCount = 0;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        questionView = findViewById(R.id.question_view);
        nextButton = findViewById(R.id.next_button);

        displayQuestion();

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            displayQuestion();
        }
    });
}

public void displayQuestion() {

    // This methods queries your database for a question with the Id of an random integer from 1 to 30 and sets the text of the TextView to the question text

    final Query questionToDisplay = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference().child("questions")
                .orderByChild("questionId")
                .equalTo(new Random().nextInt(30)); // Generate a random integer from 1 to 30

        questionToDisplay.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot question : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (questionCount is < 10) {
                        questionView.setText(question.getValue(QuizQuestion.class).getQuestionText);
                        questionCount += 1;

                    } else if (questionCount >= 10) {
                         finish(); // Close Activity
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e("ItemDetail", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                }
            });
}
```

If you want add a question, just add these lines wherever you want -

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("questions").push
.setvalue(new QuizQuestion(1, /* Question Id */"What sound does a fox make?" /* Question Text */));
```

Hope this helps!!

EDIT:

Here is the asssumed database structure -

```
--quiz-app // Root node
    --questions
        --Lxjcksduso12m42i4m
            --questionId: "1"
            --questionText: "What sound does a fox make?"
        --Lxjcksduso12m42i4m
            --questionId: "2"
            --questionText: "What is the capital of Italy?"
        --Lxjcksduso12m42i4m
            --questionId: "3"
            --questionText: "When will the polar ice caps melt completely?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you have a questions like below image in firebase database.

[image]

```
database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
ArrayList<Question> questions;

        String categoryId = getIntent().getStringExtra("categoryId");  

           
        database.collection("categories")
                .document(categoryId)
                .collection("Questions")


                .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {


                    for(DocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        Question question = snapshot.toObject(Question.class);
                        questions.add(question);

                    }
                Collections.shuffle(questions);
}
});
```

In my case, I have a category (for example computer category, software category) and in each category we have a collection of questions Therefore we get a specific categoryId to display questions of specific category.
first you get all the question from database and add in a list like `questions.add(question);` if all the added in a list then you shuffle the questions in the list, `Collections.shuffle(questions);`
so each time you get different questions.